# vim R plugin installation issues on Ubuntu in Android phone

Tags: android, vim, ubuntu

There was another thread on vim-R-plugin but since it was bit old, I started this new thread. Also my situation is kind of different, since I am trying this on a mobile device, Samsung vibrate.

I was following instructions in [this site](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-installation):

I got stuck installing a R package called *vimcom*. No matter how I tried it always come up with the error :

```
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace()for 'vimcom', details:.......
........................
```

Ubuntu version is maverick: 10.14
R-version 2.11

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The post is a bit old but I had some problems too.
I was using:

- Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS
- Vim 7.4.273
- Vim-R-Plugin-1.2-3
- Vimcom-1.2-3

and unfortunately the default R version was up at 3.2.0 after upgrading all binaries with

```
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get upgrade;

R --version 
3.2.0
```

So using Ubuntu's after removing the R packages

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove r-recommended r-base r-base-core
```

apt-cache search tool to find the available older packages:

```
sudo apt-cache showpkg r-base-core
```

in this there was options for 3.1.3-1trusty0. So hence installing the generation previous was available with:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core=3.1.3-1trusty0
sudo apt-get install r-recommend=3.1.3-1trusty0 
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.1.3-1trusty0
```

Thence vimcom could be installed by the standard method and every thing worked. PS just a note, I accidentally thought removing r-base was sufficient, it wasn't - you need to remove r-base-core or you'll remain at 3.2.0. Hope that helps somebody.